# .htaccess 500 Server Error on lowercase URLs

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to make all my urls always lowercase when the user types in the url for example site.com/Personal would be site.com/personal... Ive tried 2 different ways and one doesnt work and the other gives a 500 internal server error.

500 Internal server error

```
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

doesnt work

```
 <IfModule mod_speling.c>
  CheckCaseOnly On
  </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use RewriteMap in your .htaccess file. You can only use it in your server config or virtualhost config files. Also, if you are writing RewriteRules in an .htaccess file, the leading slash (the prefix) is removed, so you won't ever match **^/(.*)** because there's never a leading slash.